# Efecto de color en Boton CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero crear un efecto en donde de derecha a izquierda aparezcan dos lineas blancas en diagonal o rectas cuando se pase el mouse sobre el boton, imagen de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No soy bueno con las animaciones, solo tengo el boton:

```css
.boton{
  background-color: #ffb618;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div className='boton'>Boton</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa los pseudoselectores before y after, cada uno te permite colocar una banda. Luego con :hover modificas las inclinaciones. El CSS que necesitas es

```
.boton{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffb618;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
  .boton:after, .boton:before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    top:0;
    left: 30%;
    background: #fde0a0f7;
    transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
    transition: 300ms;
  }
  .boton:before{
    width: 10%;
    left: 55%;  
  }  
  .boton:hover:after, .boton:hover:before{
    transform: skew(0,0)
  }
```

Y en [esta página](https://creatuweb.espaciolatino.com/sols/bandas-hover.html) puedes verlo funcionando

Comment: Me parece super util tu comentario porque no sabia como hacer las lineas, gracias